# Property of the difference quotient in Evans(Partial Differential Equations)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Why holds the property of the difference quotient in Evans(Partial Differential Equations)
\begin{equation}
\int_{U}v D_k^{-h}dx = -\int_U w D_k^hv dx
\end{equation}
for $v,w \in H^{1}_0(U)$ (16) in Evan's book, page 311.
Where the difference quotient is given by
\begin{equation}
D_k^hu(x) = \dfrac{u(x+he_k) -u(x)}{h} \ (h \in \mathbb{R}, h\neq 0).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be presumed that in these difference quotients, one considers $u(x)$ to be zero when $x\notin u$. Then all the integrals can be taken over $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now write $$h\int vD_k^{-h}\,dx=\int v(x)u(x-he_k)\,dx-\int v(x)u(x)\,dx$$
and change variables in the former integral on the right, replacing $x$ by $x+he_k$.
Then collect the two integrals into one again, and voilà.